# How to reflect a field that implements map interface?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to get the value of the following field via reflection:

```
Map<String,ClassLoader> loaders0 = new LinkedHashMap<String,ClassLoader>();
```

but when I try to get the value using `field.get(new LinkedHashMap())`, I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Map field loaders0 to java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

and seeing as Map is an interface I could not make a new Map interface to set it too. Does anybody know how to get around this?

```
    Field loadersField = this.getPluginLoader().getClass().getDeclaredField("loaders0");
    toggleFinal(loadersField);
    Map<String, PluginClassLoader> loaders0 = (Map<String, PluginClassLoader>) loadersField.get(new LinkedHashMap<String, PluginClassLoader>());
    loaders0.put(description.getName(), bcl);
    loadersField.set(Map.class,loaders0);
```

Comment: You use `field.get()` with an instance whose class has the field.

Comment: Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis even when I do that I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.util.Map field loader to java.lang.Class`

Comment: @tieTYT I added the block of code that deals with this

Comment: Also edited the error message and field for the new code

Comment: Maps don't have that field; use the instance you're trying to set to as the first argument to `set`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement

```
loadersField.set(Map.class,loaders0);
```

means that you are trying to set the field `loader` of the object `Map.class` the value `loaders0`.

What you want is to call that on an instance of your Class that has the field `loader`.

```
loadersField.set(yourInstance, loader0);
```

Here's the correct usage of those methods:

```
public class MyClass {
    public Map<String, ClassLoader> loader = new LinkedHashMap<String, ClassLoader>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Field field = MyClass.class.getField("loader");
            MyClass instance = new MyClass();
            Map<String, ClassLoader> loader = (Map<String, ClassLoader>) field.get(instance);
            System.out.println(loader.size()); // prints 0
            Map<String, ClassLoader> newLoader = new LinkedHashMap<String, ClassLoader>();
            newLoader.put("adsas", null);
            field.set(instance, newLoader);
            loader = (Map<String, ClassLoader>) field.get(instance); 
            System.out.println(loader.size()); // prints 1
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

This class has a field `loader`, which you can get and set with the above.

Comment: @Dakota628 Then you need to pass an instance of the PluginLoader class to the `Field#get()` method.